# SOQL Query Accounts (from selected IDs) without contacts

Tags: soql

The SOQL to get all Accounts without any contacts

```
Select Id, Name From Account Where Id NOT IN (Select AccountId From Contact)
```

Is there a way to modify this query in order to filter Accounts down by a list of Ids or names?

I tried writting

```
Select Id, Name 
From Account 
Where Id NOT IN (Select AccountId From Contact)
AND Id In ('0012p00004RbtfY',
'0011t00000Mfi8T',
'0011t00000MfifT',
'0012p00003pYrBd',
'0012p00003yLuuI',
'0012p000048XcJE')
```

but this is not working. I get an error.

Comment: That query seems fine, I run it without issue. Could you please edit the question adding the error message verbatim?

Comment: Ohh damn. You are right. I run it again and it worked. It was a parsing error on a certain line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT Id, Name  FROM Account  WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId 
                 FROM Contact 
                 WHERE AccountId NOT IN ('0012p00004RbtfY',
                                         '0011t00000Mfi8T',
                                         '0011t00000MfifT',
                                         '0012p00003pYrBd',
                                         '0012p00003yLuuI',
                                         '0012p000048XcJE'))
```

In this query first exclude the accounts from the contacts and then return the account IDs.

Comment: Hello. 
So doing this, it seems that the second part has no impact.
The SOQL runs but returns all of the Accounts in SFDC that has no contacts.